# Has anyone ported Xerces C++ and Xalan C++ to iPhoneOS?

Tags: iphone

I am looking for iPhoneOS libraries for Apache's Xerces C++ and Xalan C++. Has anyone ported Xerces C++ and Xalan C++ to iPhoneOS? Any help or tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone still cares 5 years later, I was able to build and link to xerces-c for the IOS simulator:

./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ios --disable-shared --disable-pretty-make --enable-netaccessor-socket --enable-transcoder-iconv CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc CXX=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++

Then `make`/`make install`

Comment: How about for real iOS device: armv7 & arm64?

Comment: @brewphone, the problem is probably no longer actual, but Xerces-C++ (*version 3.2.4*) builds for iOS almost out of the box, just need to set `icu` transcoder (*and have ICU available in the system*). The [current vcpkg port](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/cf9152259393084fb4f72d05ec92094c6a82f76e/ports/xerces-c) in Microsoft's registry seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Can't help you with the larger question, but you might need to compile [libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859949/is-including-libcurl-in-an-iphone-app-store-app-allowed-anyone-done-this) to include it when compiling Xerces. Have you considered using `libxml2`, which is precompiled and ready to use?

Comment: does libxml2 come with SAX parser?